# How to read a data file at a package path on Lua 5.1

Tags: lua, luajit

How to read a data file at a package path on Lua 5.1?

What I'm looking for is something like a `io.read` but at the package directory instead of the working directory (`arg[0]`), and without using hardcoded absolute paths. That would be something like `dofile` does, but without running the code, only reading it as a string.

**Example**:

I have a `test` folder, the current working directory of the `test.lua` script.

There's a package `luapackage` in another folder, somewhere specified at the `LUA_PATH`enviroment variable.

`luapackage` can:

- `require("luapackage.other_module")`;
- `dofile("other_module.lua")`.

But `luapackage` can't do:

- `io.read("data.txt")`
- `io.read("luapackage/data.txt")`

Sample structure:

```
+-test/
  |
  +-test.lua

+-luamodule/
  |
  +-data.txt
  |
  +-luamodule.lua
  |
  +-other_module.lua
```

For this example, `test.lua` only requires `luamodule`:

```
-- test.lua
local luamodule = require("luamodule")
```

And `luamodule` needs to read its modules and data files:

```
-- luamodule.lua
local other_module= dofile("other_module.lua") -- works
-- local other_module= require("luamodule.other_module") -- also works

local data = io.open("data.txt") -- fails
-- local data = io.open("luamodule/data.txt") -- also fails
```

It doesn't work because it searches for the file at the working directory    (`test`) and not the package directory.

If I place a copy of the package at running script's folder, `io.read(luapackage/data.txt)` is possible. But every script would have to carry its own local copy of `luapackage`.

Note: I'm looking for a Lua solution, avoiding binary packages that could compromise cross-compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debug.getinfo(1,"S").source` to get the location of the current (module) file. Replace `luamodule.lua` with `data.txt`, remove leading `@`, and you should get the path you need.

Comment: Thank you very much!

`local PATH = string.match(debug.getinfo(1,"S").source, "^@(.+/)[%a%-%d_]+%.lua$")` and *voilà*!